# Is this a safe way to secure against sql injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Is this code 100% safe from sql injection:

```
$id = $_GET['id']
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < ' . (int)$id);
```

or do I have to do this?

```
$id = $_GET['id']
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < ' . mysql_real_escape_string($id));
```

Comment: Your second code block has an SQL-injection hole in it because you didn't double quote the output from `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query could still blow up if `$_GET['id']` is empty, or `(int)$_GET['id']` evaluates to empty. You'd end up with a syntax error in the query. It's not enough to blindly escape or type-cast a value and stuff it into a query. You have to check that the final "safe" value is actually safe and not just a wolf in grandma's clothes.

Answer (score 2):

This article seems to be a good one in explaining how mysql_real_escape_string can protect you from SQL Injection, but it also explains its "holes"

http://www.webappsec.org/projects/articles/091007.shtml

Answer (score 2):

This

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < ' . mysql_real_escape_string($id));
```

would be bad practice. If you want it to be a string, at least quote the string:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id`<"'.mysql_real_escape_string($id)).'"';
```

(and while you're at it, quote all field and table names as well, for things like `id` might be or become reserved keywords at some point)

I would prefer the cast, if it is an integer. One argument for the string version would be that some day the id might be alphanumeric (as seen more and more often on a lot of websites).

Answer (score 0):

I use `sprintf`, `mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < %d', $id));`

Comment: This is not very safe because if $id is not an int it will be converted to an int. Which if $id="xyz" then it will be "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < 0"

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: He says to prevent sql injection, and this works. Cast is not the problem in this moment I think.

Comment: No it doesn't work because if it was DELETE * FROM mytable WHERE id > %d, then I can make it delete everything by just doing id > 0. Not so good!!!

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: Wow, how many sql's 'DELETE * FROM mytable WHERE id > %d' do you use? I never used this.

Comment: I was giving you an example. You can write code that protects against only one case by doesn't protect against all SQL injections. You don't have a basis for your argument. If you let $id be 0 in some cases then I am sure you can think of a few situations of where that could be bad. You should always check to see if $id is of type int, no exception.

Comment: I did not say at any time that your choice is wrong, but you 
said the mine is unsafe and I do not agree with that, sprintf is a 
way to avoid sql injection, you can see in 
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php.

Comment: @Cesar, it works for int, but sucks for strings, because you did not state in your answer that it really only valid for ints, for which it works great BTW *(for you don't mind `'gdhsg' == 0`)* I have to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameterised queries. Then you don't need to worry about all that escaping. It also makes the SQL much easier to read. Oh and don't use select *, just select what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**No**
you have to do this:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
//put the escaped string in a $var, so your select statement stays readable
//this will help in debugging, and make **not** forgetting those vital quotes
//easier.
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < '$id'";
//                                         ^   ^always single quote your $vars
//       ^                                      ^ and double quote the query 
$result = mysql_query($query);
//and test to see if your query ran successful.
if (!$result) { //your query gave an error, handle it gracefully.
```

Then you're safe.

Comment: Oldscool answer. As mentioned in other answers: use parameterised queries.

Comment: It's of little use repeating everyone elses answer, this is the way to make mysql_real_escape_string() safe. No question PDO is better though. But given the wrong usage of that function with that really long name I'd thought I'd point out how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Why give advice that one shouldn't follow, not answering the actual question (see discussion on my answer). Your "no" is still strange to me. but i'll leave you to your findings, though I think it is incorrect you've awarded my answer with a -1.

Comment: @Nanne, mysql_real_escape_string() used properly is every bit as safe as PDO. In fact I can do injection with PDO as well. e.g. if I do dynamic table names SQL-injection is wide open with PDO. So PDO offers exactly the same level of protection as **proper** use of `mysql_real_escape_string()` does.

Answer (score -1):

It is safe but you probably want to do

```
if(is_int($id)){
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < ' . mysql_real_escape_string($id)); // just to be safe always to escape
}
```

Comment: I only think this is better because you want to fail gracefully instead of having a broken application when $id is not an int